# SQL varchar to numeric error, with no varchar fields envolved

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, numeric, varchar

i´m trying to build a query, and got stuck in this place where i´m getting an error: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Here´s the code:

```
    SELECT convert(numeric,convert(decimal(7,4), 
(
(SELECT SUM(pn.etiliquido-pn.qtt*pn.epcusto) from pn where (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-06-08') and 
(pn.usr1 not like '%'+'Portes'+'%') and (no like '517936') and (pn.epcusto > '0'))) 

/ 


(SELECT SUM((pn.etiliquido)) from pn where (pn.fdata BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-08') and 
(pn.usr1 not like '%'+'Portes'+'%') and (no like '517936') and (pn.epcusto > '0')) *100 +'%'))
  as Rentabilidade
```

None of the tables i´m calling has varchar data, i´m not getting what i´m doing wrong...

Comment: `X like 'varchar'` requires `X` be cast to a varchar for the comparison.

Comment: Why are you nesting so many calls to `CONVERT`?  Besides this, the error could be happening anywhere you are treating numbers as strings or vice-versa.

Comment: well, the result without the converts is something like:
9662200.3200001
and i wanted it to output something like:
9662200,32 €

i´ve done it this way in other selects but this, specifically, doesn´t seem to work dont know why...

Answer (score 0):

well, thanks any way. just by removing 2 Parenthesis i managed to do what i wanted in the beginning. guess what the problem was i was isolating the wrong variable.